# I came home and realized that I had not closed [the/a] window

Tags: articles

The situation is: I came home and realized that one window in my house is open (because e.g. it was colder than it should be), but I didn't know which one exactly (my house has several windows). Which article should I use?

> I came home and realized that I had not closed [the/a] window.

Comment: Better ways to say this:  "I realized I had not closed one of the windows" or "I realized I left a window open".  "The" implies there is only one window, or that the speaker knows which window was left open.  But "I left the window open" sounds a little better, even if you don't know which window it is.

Comment: Unless you have somehow identified the window to your reader (or there is only one window in the house) you'd use (ta da!) the *indefinite article*.

Comment: @swbarnes2, that's a good alternative suggestion, but they really do mean the same thing in this case. It should be *realised I **had** left a window open*.

Answer (score 1):

In my opinion either is acceptable, with caveats:

If you have a particular window in mind, then *the window* refers to that (but the reader wouldn't know *which window* other than it referring to *the one that had been left open*).

When you don't know which window yet, then saying *a window* is indeed possibly more “correct”, but for the reader, nothing has changed: we still don't know *which window* (unless you were writing a book and were able to add illustrations). There is also the problem that it can parse a bit more like *realized I had failed to close a [single] window* ... meaning *I had left all the windows open*.

I'd probably say ***had forgotten to close*** (the|a) window myself, but it's in no way “better” than your version(s).

The only bad option would be to say *a window* if you only had one window in the house :o).

Comment: I'd be far happier with '... shut the door' here than '... shut the window', probably because the implication is that the door must be specified as the one you left by. ' ... shut the window' needs a modicum of prior context ( ... [of the room I'd been sitting in, mentioned before in the text]).

Comment: If your last complaint is addressed to me, perhaps you should know that the downvote wasn't mine. I can prove it (and may well do if your comment isn't removed).